# PHP умножение данных массива по принципу 1-2|1-3|2-3

Tags: php, массивы, динамические-массивы

Есть динамический массив принципа:

```
Array ( [sum] => 1 [k1] => 1 [w1] => 1 [k2] => 2 [w2] => 1 [k3] => 3 [w3] => 1 [first] => 2 [second] => 3 )
```

Как можно сделать умножение значений массива по принципу - выдирать ключ k и перемножать значения по принципу `1-2|1-3|2-3` && `1-2|1-3|1-4|2-3|2-4|3-4` с первого по последнее, со второго по последнее и т.д.

Comment: Эм... Брать значения из массива и перемножать?

Comment: Да, но если массив динамический? Немного не могу понять, если делать в цикле, то как правильно сделать сам цикл

Comment: если массив "динамический", то будьте добры нормально описать принцип перемножения. Какие ключи и по какому правилу перемножать. выдрать все `k` ключи и умножать вида `1-2|1-3|2-3|2-4|3-4|3-5` или как? пока что принцип не ясен

Comment: Да, совершенно верно, извиняюсь за неточность пояснения, выдирать ключи k и перемножать по принципу 1-2|1-3|2-3 && 1-2|1-3|1-4|2-3|2-4 итд.

Comment: то есть умножать с первого до последнего, потом со второго до последнего, с третьего до последнего? почему в вашем втором примере нет пары `3-4`?

Comment: Упустил, да, с первого до последнего, со второго, с третьего и т.д. Массив увеличивается от вводимых данных, далее результаты записываются в таблицу.

Comment: а с парами то этими чего делать надо после умножения? складывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не совсем ясно, что надо со всем этим делать, но допустим, если надо сложить произведение  таких пар, то код может быть следующим:

Исходные:

```
$data = [ "sum" => 1, "k1" => 1, "w1" => 1, "k2" => 2, "w2" => 1, "k3" => 3, "w3" => 1, "first" => 2, "second" => 3 ];
```

Фильтруем нужные ключи

```
$kdata = array_filter($data, function($k){ return preg_match('/^k\d+$/', $k);}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Считаем формулу

```
$result = 0;
while($kdata){
    $el = array_shift($kdata);
    $result += $el*array_sum($kdata);
}
```

Пока массив не пустой, берем первый элемент, и считаем сумму его произведений на оставшиеся элементы.

> А как считать по принципу: первый элемент на второй и запись в таблицу, первый элемент на третий и так же запись в таблицу?

а так и считать. пишите двойной цикл и формируете массив вставляемых значений. Потом подготавливаете sql запрос и в цикле выполняете его по сформированному массиву.

```
$kdata = array_values($kdata);

$import = [];
foreach($kdata as $i1 => $v1){
    for($i2 = $i1 + 1; $i2 < count($kdata); $i2++){
        $import[] = [
                ':idx_1' => $i1 + 1,
                ':idx_2' => $i2 + 1,
                ':v_1'   => $v1,
                ':v_2'   => $kdata[$i2],
                ':res'   => $v1 * $kdata[$i2],
            ];
    }
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (idx_1, idx_2, v1, v2, res) VALUES (:idx_1, :idx_2, :v_1, :v_2, :res)");
foreach($import as $v){
    $stmt->execute($v);
}
```

Comment: Почти то, что нужно! А как считать по принципу: первый элемент на второй и запись в таблицу, первый элемент на третий и так же запись в таблицу?

Comment: @funforlifefix дополнил. можно варьировать алгоритм в зависимости от вставляемых данных.

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что нужно!